# Measure of the sum of sets

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

For $X$ and $Y$ two random variables such that $\mid X \mid \leq a$ holds with probability at least $\lambda$, and $\mid Y \mid \leq b$ holds with probability at least $\beta$. We can say that $\mid X \mid + \mid Y \mid \leq a+b$ holds with probability at least $\min\{\lambda,\beta\}$ ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}P(\lvert X\rvert+\lvert Y\rvert\le a+b)&\ge P(\lvert X\rvert\le a, \lvert Y\rvert\le b)=\\&=P(\lvert X\rvert\le a)+P(\lvert Y\rvert\le b)-P(\lvert X\rvert\le a\lor \lvert Y\rvert\le b)\ge\\&\ge \lambda+\beta-1 \end{align}$$

This establishes a lower bound of $\max\{\lambda+\beta-1,0\}$. For tightness consider $X,Y:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$, $$X(t)=\begin{cases}a&\text{if }0\le t\le \lambda\\ a+1&\text{if }\lambda<t\le 1\end{cases}\\ Y(t)=\begin{cases}b+1&\text{if }0\le t\le 1-\beta\\ b&\text{if }1-\beta<t\le 1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks it's useful for me.